# Factorial of a number in C

Tags: c, variables, factorial

So I was Writing a program to print the factorial of a number in C. My code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a,i ;
    printf("Enter the number = ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    for(i=1; i<a; i++)
    {
        a = a*i;
    }
    printf("The factorial of the given number is = %d\n",a);
}
```

Now this program is printing some garbage value. I asked some friends and they said to add another variable for factorial and use the loop with that factorial variable, but none of them knew why is this code wrong.

My question is as to why is this code wrong? What is this For loop doing here and why is it not printing the factorial of the number, but some garbage value?

Expected output-

```
Enter the number = 5
The factorial of the given number is = 120
```

The Output that I am getting is-

```
Enter the number = 5
The factorial of the given number is = -1899959296
```

Comment: "this program is printing some garbage value" Show that please, along with the output you expect. Make sure you define the input to trigger that behaviour. Low and high values.

Comment: Init your `a` and try again. You currently have potential undefined behaviour.

Comment: maybe an integer overflow in `a`.

Comment: @Yunnosch Alright, I put my expected output and the output I got here.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. What happens if you init `a` and maybe output it after your attempt to read it in? What is the return value of your scanf() call if you output it for verification? It should be 1 you know....

Comment: You are advancing the end check, which cannot be `true` until overflow has happened.

Comment: @Yunnosch Of course I know that math about factorial. No need to be rude. I am just trying to get my doubt cleared here, What I thought here is that the loop will start from i =1 and go upto i<5, and since we already have starting integer a = 5, it should multiple a (that is 5 here) to 1, then this is stored in a, and this product should again be multiplied to i (that will be 2 in the next run). Continuing like this, it should print 5*1*2*3*4.

Comment: @WeatherVane what does that mean, I thought like "the loop will start from i =1 and go upto i<5, and since we already have starting integer a = 5, it should multiple a (that is 5 here) to 1, then this is stored in a, and this product should again be multiplied to i (that will be 2 in the next run). Continuing like this, it should print 5*1*2*3*4."

Comment: I did not intend to be rude and still do not see where you think I was. Would you like to point out what you considered rude? However, you are not far from the privilege to flag posts for problems. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts if you seriously feel that something is rude, please flag it. Including if it is by me.

Comment: It chases a rabbit down a hole, can you see that? In each loop, `a` is even bigger, until you get integer overflow, when it can appear to be less. You compare with a *moving target*.

Comment: By the way, I was side-tracked by risky programming. I am convinced that Weather Vane is right.

Comment: @Yunnosch "Can you ask the author? Isn't that you?, Are you aware of the definition of the factorial? because "I found this code which I do not understand and if I use it outside of its assumptions, specification and preconditions it does not work." is not considered a question on StackOverflow."  All of this seems like you're kinda mocking me here because I asked a basic question. No offence to you though :)

Comment: I see. Thanks for letting me know. I can see why you feel that. I will now delete that. Please understand that asking about the reason for a for loop which you wrote yourself made me think that you are asking about how to fix code which you found somewhere and were trying to hand in as a homework without understanding it (many SO users are a little edgy about that). I was under the (wrong) impression that the code should work if used within its limits by the way, or it would have been more obvious to me what you were asking and why. Thanks for taking no offense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because when you increment your variable `a`, the for loop condition change.
You have that `i` must be lesser than `a`, but incrementing `a` will cause the condition to always be true.
You have to save the value in another variable, like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a, i;

    printf("Enter the number = ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    int result = a;
    
    for(i=1; i<a; i++){
        result = result*i;
    }
    
    printf("The factorial of the given number is = %d \n", result);
}
```

Comment: Variables do no have infinite values. They overflow, and the truncated value might then be less than `i`. Integer overflow ==> garbage value. Even when corrected 13! will overflow, again giving a garbage value.

Comment: Oh I see, so the loop ran till it oveflowed into the memory and the memory wasn't able to store the variable.. Thanks mate, I get it now :)

Comment: No problem, glad it helped! Have a really nice day mate! :D

Comment: @vxlp You as well mate :)

Comment: You can easily handle the case of 0! properly by setting the initial value of result to 1 and then modifying the FOR statement to read "for (i = 2; i <= a; i++) {"